# Widgets are not showing after moving domain

Tags: widgets, domain, migration

I recently moved my wordpress installation to a new domain. Everything worked fine; all my images, posts and plugins copied across fine. My widget setup seems to be gone after moving domain. I can see the setup in the database but nothing on the page. Is it some manual thing you have to do to get the widgets to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Redrag and drop them in the widgets area.

Answer (score 0):

Put this function into `functions.php` in the `wp-include` folder:

```
function maybe_unserialize( $original ) {
    if ( is_serialized( $original ) ) {
        $fixed = preg_replace_callback(
            '!(?<=^|;)s:(\d+)(?=:"(.*?)";(?:}|a:|s:|b:|i:|o:|N;))!s',
            'serialize_fix_callback',
            $original );
        return @unserialize( $fixed );
    }
    return $original;
}
function serialize_fix_callback($match) { return 's:' . strlen($match[2]); }
```

Comment: Please, use the WYSIWYG tools to properly format you Answer. An explanation about what the code does is welcome as well.